# How to add vertical stack from button (user input) [Xcode]

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield, uistackview, nib

I'm trying to create a form where you will input reps and weight (ints) into two textfields which is in a vertical stack. The problem I have is when the user is doing more than 1 set, i want to (via the plus button) add another of this vertical stack so the user can input weight and reps again, basically creating two more textfields underneath.[Picture of my current layout in the Nib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkMPV.png)

Right now im doing everything in my customtableviewcell (look at pic). So I don't really have any specific code to attach.

Thankful for any help, and please ask if there is something unclear from my question (I will make sure to clarify as good as I can)

Greetings, Pontus

Comment: Unclear what the question is. Clearly you will need code to append another "row" on demand.

Comment: @matt In that case the question is how to write the code to do this, i think there should be questions similar/forums etc where this is explained but i couldnt find it. Maybe you have any tips or know where i could find guidance? :)